# Display the node value of given xml in proper format as mentioned with their tag

Tags: xslt

Input document format

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>I am normal</p>
        <p style="color:red;">I am<b> r<i>e</i>d</b></p>
        <p style="color:blue;">I am <b>blue</b></p>
        <p><b>I am <i>big</i></b></p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Expected Output (taken from post authors comments)

```
<sp:html xmlns:"urn:unknown">
    <sp:body>
        <sp:p>I am normal</sp:p>
        <sp:p>I am <sp:b emphasis="true">r <sp:i emphasis="true">
                    <sp:color textforecolor="red">e</sp:color>
                </sp:i>
            </sp:b>d </sp:p>
        <sp:p>I am <sp:b emphasis="true">
                <sp:color textforecolor="blue">blue</sp:color>
            </sp:b>
        </sp:p>
        <sp:p>
            <sp:b>I am<sp:span> </sp:span><sp:i>big</sp:i></sp:b>
        </sp:p>
    </sp:body>
</sp:html>
```

The author would like to know how to transform the input into the given output.

Comment: What is this question? Please go through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrase your question providing all the details.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>I am normal</p>
<p style="color:red;">I am<b> r<i>e</i>d</b></p>
<p style="color:blue;">I am <b>blue</b></p>
<p><b>I am <i>big</i></b></p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: This is the html code format

Comment: I want to transform it into xml

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure sir
This is the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>I am normal</p>
<p style="color:red;">I am<b> r<i>e</i>d</b></p>
<p style="color:blue;">I am <b>blue</b></p>
<p><b>I am <i>big</i></b></p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @RakeshBurbure
Sir I can't able to post my html code fragment

Comment: @Pratzz Please do not post code in comments. [edit] your post to provice complete information on what you're asking.

Comment: Ohk @JimGarrison Sir

Comment: @Pratzz: I can see HTML code, not xml code.can you please check and edit the code accordingly. More description you add to the question, more chances of getting your issue resolved.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure sir isko html mein hi convert karna hai 
aur html pe hi transformation lagana hai using xslt

Comment: @Pratzz It would be more helpful if you also post the expected output. _Text format_ is preferred but even if _image_ that would also be _OK_.

Comment: @Pratzz There are so many people here to help you out. But _it is unfortunate that your are not able to clear your problem_. :(

Comment: @Pratzz : just to simplify, tell us what will be your input and what output your are expecting.

Comment: Sir My expected output is
<sp:html>
    <sp:body>
        <sp:p >I am normal</sp:p>
        <sp:p>I am
            <sp:b emphasis="true">r
                <sp:i emphasis="true">
                    <sp:color textforecolor="red">e</sp:color>
                </sp:i>
            </sp:b>d
        </sp:p>
        <sp:p>I am
            <sp:b emphasis="true">
                <sp:color textforecolor="blue">blue</sp:color>
            </sp:b>
        </sp:p>
        <sp:p>
            <sp:b>I am<sp:span> </sp:span><sp:i>big</sp:i></sp:b>
        </sp:p>
    </sp:body>
</sp:html>

Comment: Again I'm Very sorry I'm can't able to post my expected output in my question @JimGarrison

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Sir I'm posted my expected output .
Please Help me sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your question (added the expected output to it).

This stylesheet comes close to what you posted as expected output in the comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sp="urn:whatever"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <sp:b emphasis="true">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sp:b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="i">
        <sp:i emphasis="true">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sp:i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="sp:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, there are some problems to reach your expected output:

- I have added a random namespace `xmlns:sp="urn:whatever"` since you did not provide one
- there is a **structural difference** between input and output for the color. While the color in the input is on the paragraph level (`p style="color:red;"`), it is in the output only applied to a part of the paragraph. I don't see here the "rule" how to apply the color.
- tags like `<b>` are the **same in the input, but have different results in the output** (`<sp:i>` vs `<sp:i emphasis="true">`). You cannot have different results for the same input. There must be clear transformation rules.

If you have clear transformation rules, you should be able to complete the stylesheet for your needs.

Comment: Thank u so much @burki

Comment: You're welcome. I think you were not able to successfully edit your question because the HTML code was not properly indented. Next time copy/paste your code into a text editor, fix the indentation and copy/paste it back into your question. That way you should be able to get rid of the validation errors that say that you have not indented code.

Comment: Ohk @burki sir. Your answer is very helpfull for me.